# Does this question fit anywhere?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm looking for a ISP in the UK that allows personal/home/non-commercial customers to have a static IP. Would this question fit on any SE site? I think whilst there could be a definite answer, something about it seems like it would be off-topic everywhere

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Would this question fit on any SE site?

No.

It is essentially a [shopping question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), there may be multiple valid answers and any answer that is correct today may be incorrect tomorrow.

The question also suffers from being rather broad in selection criteria on one side (non-commercial ISP that offers static IPs), and being overly narrow on the other (in the UK).

---

It might be possible to formulate it to describe the requirements first, then seeing if anyone has a solution (you may be surprised and get an answer that doesn't relate to a specific ISP).

Without seeing the actual requirements (i.e. why a static IP? Why a non-commercial ISP?), it isn't really easy to think of an appropriate site.

Comment: Okay, I'll go search on some forums, although my luck with getting an answer there recently hasn't been good :P. If I don't find anything I'll try and structure it into a more fitting question.